# python django: convert the postgresql timestamp to datetime

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a postgresql table with a timestamp field, among other fields.

How can I convert this timestamp field to a standard datetime python object and get the date like this: "Apr 23"

I know how to do it in the django template (with the 'date' template tag), I need to do in views.py so I can create an array with these dates and pass it to the django template.

Comment: Well, if you are using a Django model, and you are using a models.DateTimeField(), Django's ORM will take care of the details of translating from the database format to a Python datetime object. Once you have it as a Python datetime object, you can print it out in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
TIME_FORMAT = "%b %d"
f_str = obj.date.strftime(TIME_FORMAT)
```

or

```
TIME_FORMAT = "%b %d"
arr = [d.strftime(TIME_FORMAT) for d in dates]
```

[strftime formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)